# Apply set_index over groupby object in order to apply asfreq per group

Tags: pandas

Im looking to apply `pading` over each group of my data frame

notice that for a single group ('element_id') i have no problem in pading:

first group (group1):

```
{'date': {88: datetime.date(2017, 10, 3), 43: datetime.date(2017, 9, 26), 159: datetime.date(2017, 11, 8)}, u'element_id': {88: 122, 43: 122, 159: 122}, u'VALUE': {88: '8.0', 43: '2.0', 159: '5.0'}}
```

So im applying padding over it (which works great):

```
print group1.set_index('date').asfreq('D', method='pad').head()
```

Im looking to apply this logic over several groups through `groupby`

Another group (group2):

```
{'date': {88: datetime.date(2017, 10, 3), 43: datetime.date(2017, 9, 26), 159: datetime.date(2017, 11, 8)}, u'element_id': {88: 122, 43: 122, 159: 122}, u'VALUE': {88: '8.0', 43: '2.0', 159: '5.0'}}

group_data=pd.concat([group1,group2],axis=0)
group_data.groupby(['element_id']).set_index('date').resample('D').asfreq()
```

And im getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'set_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First there is problem your `date` column has `dtype` object, not datetime, so first is necessary convert it by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Then is possible use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
group_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(group_data['date'])

df = (group_data.groupby(['element_id'])
                .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('D').ffill()))

print (df.head())

                      VALUE  element_id
element_id date                        
122        2017-09-26   2.0         122
           2017-09-27   2.0         122
           2017-09-28   2.0         122
           2017-09-29   2.0         122
           2017-09-30   2.0         122
```

Or [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html):

```
    df = group_data.set_index('date').groupby(['element_id']).resample('D').ffill()
print (df.head())
                      VALUE  element_id
element_id date                        
122        2017-09-26   2.0         122
           2017-09-27   2.0         122
           2017-09-28   2.0         122
           2017-09-29   2.0         122
           2017-09-30   2.0         122
```

EDIT:

If problem with duplicates values solution is add new column for subgroups with unique `dates`. If use `concat` there is parameter `keys` for it:

```
group1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': {88: datetime.date(2017, 10, 3), 
                                43: datetime.date(2017, 9, 26), 
                                159: datetime.date(2017, 11, 8)}, 
                       u'element_id': {88: 122, 43: 122, 159: 122}, 
                       u'VALUE': {88: '8.0', 43: '2.0', 159: '5.0'}})


d = {'level_0':'g'}
group_data=pd.concat([group1,group1], keys=('a','b')).reset_index(level=0).rename(columns=d)
print (group_data)
     g VALUE        date  element_id
43   a   2.0  2017-09-26         122
88   a   8.0  2017-10-03         122
159  a   5.0  2017-11-08         122
43   b   2.0  2017-09-26         122
88   b   8.0  2017-10-03         122
159  b   5.0  2017-11-08         122


group_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(group_data['date'])

df = (group_data.groupby(['g','element_id'])
                .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('D').ffill()))

print (df.head())

                         g VALUE  element_id
g element_id date                           
a 122        2017-09-26  a   2.0         122
             2017-09-27  a   2.0         122
             2017-09-28  a   2.0         122
             2017-09-29  a   2.0         122
             2017-09-30  a   2.0         122
```

Comment: Im getting the following error: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: I test it and you are right, I add solution for this problem.

Comment: I test it with `group_data=pd.concat([group1,group2],axis=0)` and then it is impossiblw, because duplicates `date`s per group :(

Comment: Yep, that's exactly my problem :)

Comment: Inanswer was added solution for it.